# Core graphics drag over pixels instead of points

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, drawrect, pixel

Ok, I haven't found it anywhere. What should I do if i want to draw with core graphics per pixel? Like… I want to draw a line to pixels (45,61) and than (46,63) instead of drawing to point (23,31) or something like that. So what should I do in this case?

Should I use something like:

```
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,22.5,30.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,23,31.5);
```

Or there is some better way?

I know about `contentScaleFactor` but should I use it as (*when plotting some function for example*):

```
for(int x=bounds.origin.x; x<=bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width*[self contentScaleFactor]; i++)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,x/[self contentScaleFactor],y(x/[self contentScaleFactor]));
```

I know that the example code is not superb, but I think you'll get the idea.

I'll be vey thankful for help because I'm a bit confused with all this *scale factor* stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing the Assignment3 from the iOS uTunes Stanford Course? :)
I think you are on the right track, as my implementation looks very similar:

```
for(int x=self.bounds.origin.x; x<=self.bounds.origin.x + (self.bounds.size.width * self.contentScaleFactor); x++) {
    // get the scaled X Value to ask dataSource
    CGFloat axeX = (x/self.contentScaleFactor - self.origin.x) / self.scale;

    // using axeX here for testing, which draws a x=y graph
    // replace axeX with the dataSource Y-Point calculation
    CGFloat axeY = -1 * ((axeX * self.scale) + self.origin.y); 

    if (x == self.bounds.origin.x) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x/self.contentScaleFactor, axeY);
    } else {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x/self.contentScaleFactor, axeY);          
    }
}
```

Tested on iOS-Sim iPhone4 (contentScaleFactor 1.0) + iPhone4S Device (contentScaleFactor 2.0).
Would be happy about possible improvements from other readers, because I am still learning.

Comment: I have completely the same solution. Accept the handling of first x (but it's not affecting scalfactor stuff :) )